# Centering div with image which uses bootstrap classes

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, alignment

I am trying to center an image on the page, but it only works for mobile screens because I put `col-xs-12` for `<img>` tag. Is there any problem in this class:

```
col-md-6 col-xs-12 img-responsive text-center
```

I tried to put `margin: 0 auto` to `<img>` and to `.pict` div, but it doesn't work. Also, I've tried `center-block` class and `text-center`.

```
<div class="container" style="width: 100%">
    <div class="pict" style="width: 100%">
        <div class="img-pict" style="margin: 0 auto">
            <img src="../img/CoverCNVol1No1.png" class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 img-responsive text-center">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The image is standing on the left side, it should be at the center of the screen.

Comment: Start with the [Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/layout/grid/#grid-options). There is no longer `col-xs` or `img-responsive` in Bootstrap 4.

Comment: `.img-responsive` has been renamed to `.img-fluid` in v4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is using the bootstrap container classes col-md-6 and alike to size containers for the image for different screen sizes and put the img inside.

You can convert the image to inline element using `display: inline-block;` and use the bootstrap `text-center` class or `text-align: center;` on the container div.

Or you can leave the image as is (block element) and center it with `margin: auto` or bootstrap4 `mx-auto` on the container div.

Also have in mind that for horizontal centering you are setting the left and right margins to auto. Top and bottom can still be sized as you need them.

```
<div class="container" style="width: 100%;">
  <div class="pict" style="width: 100%;">
    <div style="margin: auto;" class="img-pict col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        <img src="../img/CoverCNVol1No1.png" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is still on the left side, just the size goes to original

Comment: Did you include the `margin: auto;` on the div img is inside?

Comment: it works now, thank you